# Question about interaction between some message-functions()

Tags: assembly, encryption

i have found the following code sequence in a sample which I try to analyze:

```
....
push offset LibFileName ;    "KERNEL32.DLL"
call LoadLibraryA
mov esi, eax
test esi, esi
jz short loc_40EDF2
lea edx, [ebp+var_108]
...
...
mov eax, offset aUmehyJ ; "UmehyJ{j"
push eax                ; lpProcName
push esi                ; hModule
call GetProcAddress_0
```

So, I know what the combination of LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress does. But what I do not understand is the following line:

```
mov eax, offset aUmehyJ ; "UmehyJ{j"
```

I would say that the process name is somehow encrypted. I searched a little bit and read that XOR-encryption in combination with a loop is frequently used in malware. So, I let IDA PRO search all occurences of a XOR and try to locate of course those with a register-immediate combination, for example xor eax, 12h.
But I could not find something like this.

After that, I have read that Base64 encoding is also used in malware. So, I type the string "UmehyJ{j" in a online Base64 decoder tool ( http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ ) but without success.

So, now I am at a point where I do not know how I should make the next steps.
Because of that, I hope somebody can help me.

best regards,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the function name appears to be encrypted.

You can double-click on `aUmehyJ` in IDA to see cross-references to the "UmehyJ{j" string: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ida-cross-references-xrefs/

This will allow you to find what code in the program decrypts the string before it is passed to `GetProcAddress()`.

Alternatively, you can open your target in a debugger and place a memory-write hardware-breakpoint on the first byte of the "UmehyJ{j" string and wait for the breakpoint to be hit. This will allow you to find the code that decrypts the string.

Comment: yes, I have tried that, too. I marked "offset UmehyJ{j" and click Strg+X to get the cross-reference list of offset UmehyJ{j , but in the list the mentioned line with mov eax, offset UmehyJ{j is the only place where that string appears. There is no other reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer above with an alternative approach.

Comment: hahaha...sometimes I could beat myself for my stupidity. I opened the program with ollydbg, go to mentioned place and then I see that ollydbg shows me the real name of the process. It is "RegisterServiceProcess". But thanks for your advice with the breakpoint. I´ve perceived it.

Comment: @user3097712 It's not process, it's address of the procedure. See on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)